# Viewport scaling of HTML email doesn't work when the page contains an overflowing table

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm building an HTML email, and when I have simple text on the page, the text scales up slightly in mobile clients based on the size of the viewport. I have this meta tag included: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

I also want to include a fixed-width table nested within a div. The div's style includes `overflow: auto` so the table can scroll horizontally, and not overflow its parent.

When I include the table and open the email in a mobile client, the text renders very small. It seems that the inclusion of the fixed-width table prevents the entire email from being scaled responsively.

Is there any way to fix this, and have both the table and the responsive text scaling?

Comment: Propably yes. Can you post some more code so we can recreate the issue?

Comment: Keep in mind that email clients have very limited CSS support, this is most probably not possible. Stick to simple table layouts like it's 1990 when it comes to emails.

Comment: You've got a fixed width table that extends past the width of the rest of the email and you're expecting the rest of the email to be responsive...? Just have a think proper think about that...

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein  The table’s overflow is hidden, so it doesn’t actually extend past the rest of the email. That’s why I wasn’t expecting it to affect the rest of the layout.

Comment: There is not universal support for overflow, see https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-overflow/. Post your code and we may be able to suggest a way to get the table responsive, or to re-create as cards.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is a bit too complex to extract a minimal example from; it's being mostly programmatically generated.

For anyone else finding this -- I'm probably just going to use media queries to adjust the text size and formatting on mobile devices, since they're supported on most email clients.